# How do I check my database values for the correct username and pass?

Tags: python, sql, database

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O and Logic of System)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Imports 
import sqlite3

# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for first screen
    def options_1(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Create an Account\n2. Log into Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.create()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.Log_in()
    def options_2(self): 
        ch= int(input("1. Withdraw Money from Your Account\n2. Deposit Money to Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.withdraw()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.deposit()
    # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user_create = str(input("Enter a Username:"))
        pin_create = int(input("Enter a Pin Number:" ))
        print("Account successfully created!")
     # Function to Log into Account 
    def Log_in(self):
        user = str(input("Enter your Username:"))
        pin = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        print("Welcome", user, "!")
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")

    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# Creating an object of class
self = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
self.options_1()
self.options_2()
self.display()



# PHASE 2 (With Database) SQLite 3 

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.commit()

# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(pin INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , username text )"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (7620, 'Kailas Kurup')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (4638, 'Bethany Watkins')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3482, 'John Hammond')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3493, 'Melissa Rodriguez')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (9891, 'Kevin Le')")

# Get Results / Querying Database
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

** QUESTION: How do I check my database values? For example, if I enter a username or pin value that's not in my database I will get an invalid screen. Vice versa, it will let me go through and deposit/withdraw money.

What I'm trying to do: I am creating a bank account management system where the user can deposit/withdraw money or create a new account.

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in table:
     if username in row:
        if pin in row:
            print("success")
        else:
            print("invalid pin")
```

Comment: I added this to my code but its saying username and pin aren't recognized even though they should be when I created the bank table.